# Which photoshop book?

Tags: photoshop, books

What is a good Photoshop book for photographers? I am interested in not too basic techniques (which I can more or less figure out by myself), which on the other hand give good results, without the need to be an expert pro.

Comment: Why books? Have you tried online tutorials? There are many websites with step-by-step instructions, sample files to practice with etc. Try: http://psd.tutsplus.com/ From my experience - there is little that can be found in a book that you won't find online. Also, youtube videos, Adorama Learning Center etc.

Comment: While there are a lot of Ps tutorials on line, psd.tutsplus is aimed more at graphic design with Ps than photo editing.

Comment: Good question (whoever -1'ed it should explain why BTW), you may want to phrase it 'Which photoshop book series/line?' to help the question stand the test of time.

Comment: @Jakub Kalet it is really cool site. Anyway I would prefer some book because I find it more confortable, rather than swtching betwwen CS and browser window. And I would expect some more strutured information from a book. But on the other hand with online tutorial one can choose the techniques which likes most.

Comment: It would help if you could expand the question to tell us what you want to get out of it. Different books suit different people's needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really have stopped using books, I think video's are far superior.

If you don't mind paying then take a look at [kelby's site](http://kelbytraining.com/), they have linear generalist classes as well as specific technique classes.

I agree that the nature of the internet makes it hard to put anything cohesive together, and you never know how good a technique really is.  As far as flow you might consider using a second monitor to learn and avoid the dreaded swap pattern.

Are you looking for a particular subject or just more advanced learning?

Ben Willmore http://digitalmastery.com/blog/ used to put out what was more or less a drill down of the nuts and bolts of CS for aspiring Photoshop chef's vs. short order cooks but he hasn't published anything other than e-books for awhile and the stuff on amazon is way dated.

The legendary [John Shaw](http://www.johnshawphoto.com/ebooks/) is a casual friend of mine that does really outstanding photoshop stuff in person ( he uses everything he teaches ) and he also sell's e-books which I have not used but knowing John they are probably top notch.

Other than that I would just say hit amazon, check the reviews, see what's interesting to you.

Answer (score 0):

As Jakub Kaleta said, don't go around books, in my experience internet is your best teacher, free and available 24/7!

Just try to google what you want and if you don't know where to start, check websites like psd.tutsplus.com Good luck!